# What do parameters mean when make 'new GlobalVariable'? in 'llvm FunctionPass'

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

```
GlobalVariable(Module &M, Type *Ty, bool isConstant,
                 LinkageTypes Linkage, Constant *Initializer,
                 const Twine &Name = "", GlobalVariable *InsertBefore = nullptr,
                 ThreadLocalMode = NotThreadLocal, unsigned AddressSpace = 0,
                 bool isExternallyInitialized = false);
```

I can understand these things(Module &M / Type *Ty / bool isConstant / Constant *Initializer).

But I can't understand about these. (LinkageTypes Linkage / GlobalVariable *InsertBefore / ThreadLocalMode / unsigned AddressSpace / bool isExternallyInitialized)

can you explain me? please! or please tell me how can i reference these.

I hope you're careful about Covid19. thank you.

-------- Sample Code --------

And This is Sample Code

```
      GlobalVariable *SomeGV = new GlobalVariable(
                                                        *(SomeGV->getParent()), SomeConst->getType(), false,
                                                        SomeGV->getLinkage(), SomeConst, "HelloString", nullptr,
                                                        SomeGV->getThreadLocalMode(), SomeGV->getType()->getAddressSpace());
```

Comment: You need to read the official documentation for the function `GlobalVariable`.  We on this site can't know what it means. If no documentation exists, you need to read the code. Documentation might be found in the header that declared this function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I've already looked. Sadly, there's only a very short description.

Comment: I still don't know what code you're referring to, your question lacks details. If I make a guess, I reach this website: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html

Comment: @NadavS i added some sample code.

Comment: Linkage types (and many other things too) are explained here: https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#linkage-types